# java.net.ProtocolException: Can't reset method: already connected

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I'm executing the below code in DEV environment without any issue.

```
InputStream inStream = null;
DataOutputStream dOutStream = null;
InputStream ipcInStream = null;
DataOutputStream ipcOutStream = null;
String strUser = "xxxx";
String strPswrd = "xxxxxxx";
String serverURL = "xxxxx.com";
String serverFile = "xxxx";         
String requestData = "xxxx";
// instantiate url using a defined protocol(String), url(String), port(int) and file(String)
URL urlOrder = new URL("HTTPS", serverURL, 443, serverFile);
// proxy related Code           
String proxyHost = "xxxx";
String proxyPort = "xxxx";
Proxy proxy = null;
if (proxyHost != null && proxyPort != null) {
    // Proxy instance
    proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
                    proxyHost, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)));
}
// instantiate URLConnection from URL
URLConnection urlConn = (proxy == null) ? urlOrder
                .openConnection() : urlOrder.openConnection(proxy);
// Set Input Output booleans
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);

// Set the content type of the request
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");

// Set the encoding and transfer file structure
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

// connect to the url referenced by this URLConnection
urlConn.connect();
// Get an output stream
dOutStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
dOutStream.writeBytes(requestData);
// flush the output stream
dOutStream.flush();
```

But When I run the same code in QA, I'm getting the below exception at line

```
dOutStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
```

Exception is:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Can't reset method: already connected
```

Need help on why it is throwing this exception.

Comment: Get rid of the `connect()`. It is done automatically.

Comment: If I comment connect() method and execute the code, then I'm getting the exception
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.

Comment: That sounds like progress to me. Getting it where?

Comment: giving that exception at this line dOutStream.flush();

Comment: Which is several lines of code past the previous failure point. As you are now doing I/O you are now getting a TLS handshake and the server is sending you a bad certificate. So investigate that.